# Easiest way to globally change Android font?

Tags: android

I have a ttf file, and its theoretically possible, but I'm not looking to touch over 500 different lines of code to programmatically change this. What is the easiest way?

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Typefaces.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extend [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8129052/348192) answer with static TYPEFACE:

Add new function:

```
public static void applyCustomFont(ViewGroup list, Typeface customTypeface) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View view = list.getChildAt(i);
                if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                    applyCustomFont((ViewGroup) view, customTypeface);
                } else if (view instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) view).setTypeface(customTypeface);
                }
            }
        }
```

Get root view of our Layout:

```
View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

Than apply custom font for whole activity form with all sub-elements:

```
applyCustomFont((ViewGroup)rootView, C.TYPEFACE.ArialRounded(this));
```

Answer (score 3):

I've dealt with this problem myself; although I couldn't set a custom font globally, I was able  to just make it little easier to deal with.

So in my Constants class (C.java) I have an Inner class:

```
public static final class TYPEFACE {
    public static final Typeface Helvetica(Context ctx){
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "helvetica.otf");
        return typeface;
    }
    public static final Typeface ArialRounded(Context ctx){
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "arial_rounded.ttf");
        return typeface;
    }
}
```

And in my code, after declaring and intializing the TextView I just set it's Typeface:

```
TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setTypeface(C.TYPEFACE.Helvetica(this));
```

I know this doesn't solve your problem but I hope it helps...

-serkan

Comment: I think serkan has it. There is not a global override for changing fonts. If you have already built your app, you have a lot of refactoring headed your way.

Comment: @serkan: To be safe, I would use `ctx.getApplicationContext().getAssets()`. Since you are storing these `Typeface` objects in static data members, if something in `createFromAsset()` retains a reference to the passed-in `Context`, you will leak the `Activity` you are using in your sample. Using the `Application` object is safer, as that already *is* a global instance and cannot be leaked. And, um, make sure you only use fonts that are licensed for distribution.

Comment: Not optimized code for often usage. It's will be better make "Typeface typeface" static final and initialize only in "!= null" case. This is my modification: private static Typeface arialTypeface; public static final Typeface Arial(Context ctx) {
        if (arialTypeface == null) {
            arialTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "fonts/arial.ttf");
        }
        return arialTypeface;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go would be a custom view extending TextView.  Not pretty, but you wouldn't need to copy the font code all over the place.

In all, its a pretty annoying problem for sure.